# How does require always load into the top-level scope?

Tags: ruby

Consider this Ruby code:

```
class A
  require 'json'
end
```

Because Ruby is interpreted and executes code line-by-line, I would expect JSON to be scoped inside A.

However:

```
irb(main):005:0> A::JSON
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):5
NameError (uninitialized constant A::JSON)


irb(main):004:0> JSON
=> JSON
```

How does `require` always load gems into the top-level scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is implemented [inside the VM](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/load.c#L1079), so it has access to internal functionality that normal Ruby code does not. For example it can manually escape its current scope and execute code at the top level. That is "how".

As for "why"? Imagining if you could `require` into a specific scope, this would be extremely prone to breakage since it would change top-level `self` from `main` (which is an `Object`) to... anything (in your example it would be `A`, which is a `Class`). It would be very hard to predict in general what would happen when your code is `require`d.

By always executing loaded code at the top-level, the result is always consistent. And you can use the built-in hook mechanisms (included, extended, prepended, inherited) to access specific `self`s from the scope that loaded you.

Comment: In Rubinius, `Kernel#require` is implemented in pure Ruby (not in C) and in the core library (not in the VM), and yet, it behaves exactly the same. So, the fact that one of many Ruby implementations happens to implement it in C inside the VM does not explain why `require` behaves the way it does in *all* Ruby implementations.

Comment: Regardless of how it is implemented in other Rubies, that's how it's implement in in the standard one. Not sure how else I could answer other than doing a survey of all known implementations